# Getting IndexOutOfBound Android

Tags: java, android

I have made registration demo with login functionality. While I am login with credentials, it give me IndexOutOfBoundException. Below is my required code & error log for you.

Login.java

```
package com.example.registrationexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.string;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText edt_txt_username, edt_txt_pwdActual;
    Button btn_LoginActual;
    ArrayList<RegUserGetSet> singleUserData;

    SharedPreferences sp;
    public static String sharedPref = "sharedPrefUserData";
    public static String UserFullName = "FullNameKey";
    public static String UserEmail = "EmailKey";
    public static String UserPwd = "PwdKey";
    public static String UserDOB = "DOBKey";
    public static String UserGender = "GenderKey";

    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        edt_txt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_txt_LoginEmail);
        edt_txt_pwdActual = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_txt_LoginPwd);
        btn_LoginActual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_loginActual);

        btn_LoginActual.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String username = edt_txt_username.getText().toString();
                String pwd = edt_txt_pwdActual.getText().toString();

                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getBaseContext());
                singleUserData = dbHandler.getUser(username, pwd);

                if (singleUserData.size() == 1) {
                    // sharedPref(ArrayList < Login > singleUserData);
                    sp = getSharedPreferences(sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

                    editor.putString(UserFullName, singleUserData.get(0)
                            .toString());
                    editor.putString(UserEmail, singleUserData.get(1)
                            .toString());
                    editor.putString(UserEmail, singleUserData.get(2)
                            .toString());
                    editor.putString(UserEmail, singleUserData.get(3)
                            .toString());
                    editor.putString(UserEmail, singleUserData.get(4)
                            .toString());
                    editor.commit();

                    Intent i_welcome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(i_welcome);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You are successfully login...!!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Credentials not matched...!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            private void sharedPref(ArrayList<Login> singleUserSharedPrefData) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
package com.example.registrationexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    static String DB_NAME = "users_info";
    String TABLE_NAME = "users";
    String KEY_ID = "user_id";
    String KEY_FULL_NAME = "user_full_name";
    String KEY_EMAIL = "user_email";
    String KEY_PWD = "user_pwd";
    String KEY_DOB = "user_dob";
    String KEY_GENDER = "user_gender";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_FULL_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + KEY_PWD + " TEXT, " + KEY_DOB
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long registerUser(RegUserGetSet regUserGetSet) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_FULL_NAME, regUserGetSet.getFname() + " "
                + regUserGetSet.getLname());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, regUserGetSet.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_PWD, regUserGetSet.getPwd());
        values.put(KEY_DOB, regUserGetSet.getDob());
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, regUserGetSet.getGender());

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Log.e("Inserted Data", "" + result);
        Log.e("Fname & Lname", "" + regUserGetSet.getFname() + " "
                + regUserGetSet.getLname());
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<RegUserGetSet> getAllUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<RegUserGetSet> allUsers = new ArrayList<RegUserGetSet>();
        String select_query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select_query, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RegUserGetSet singleUserObj = new RegUserGetSet();
                singleUserObj.setFname(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_FULL_NAME)));
                singleUserObj.setLname(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_FULL_NAME)));
                singleUserObj.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
                singleUserObj.setPwd(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_PWD)));
                singleUserObj.setDob(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_DOB)));
                singleUserObj.setGender(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_GENDER)));
                allUsers.add(singleUserObj);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return allUsers;
    }

    public ArrayList<RegUserGetSet> getUser(String username, String pwd) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<RegUserGetSet> singleUser = new ArrayList<RegUserGetSet>();
        String select_user = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + KEY_EMAIL + "='" + username + "' AND " + KEY_PWD + "='" + pwd
                + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select_user, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RegUserGetSet obj = new RegUserGetSet();
                // obj.setUser_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                obj.setFname(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_FULL_NAME)));
                obj.setLname(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_FULL_NAME)));
                obj.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
                obj.setPwd(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PWD)));
                obj.setDob(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DOB)));
                obj.setGender(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_GENDER)));
                singleUser.add(obj);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return singleUser;
    }
}
```

Error Log

```
    07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.example.registrationexample.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:63)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-02 13:34:22.924: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: if `singleUserData.size() == 1` how can `singleUserData.get(1)` ????

Comment: Posting whole code does not mean that you have post a good question, be specific and post the code which getting you in trouble not whole lot of this.

Comment: Sorry for that@Clairvoyant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here: `if (singleUserData.size() == 1)` you seem to be checking that the size is of 1 element. But within that same scope, you are accessing multiple items.

You would probably need to change this check: `if (singleUserData.size() == 1)` to `if (singleUserData.size() == 5)`.

Comment: But I am getting size of singleUserData equal to 1. How can I get the UserFullName, UserEmail from Arraylist singleUserData.@npinti

Comment: @MaulikM.Dodia: If you are getting 1 item but need 5, then the problem lies elsewhere. You would need to look where is the data coming and how does it make to your system.

Comment: The data is coming from getUser method of DatabaseHandler class.

Comment: @MaulikM.Dodia: Please debug the problem and ask another question should you have any difficulty.